# Angularjs - My collapse and expand is not working after filtering into text box

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angularjs having some data from ng repeat and one input text box for filter value,The data with divs are collapsible its working fine but when I filter anything into my textbox with data related to collapsed divs,the box which are already collapse its not expanding.Here is the code below and also in plunker
https://plnkr.co/edit/z4SWv6n1mfH5E4SizOPr?p=preview

### HTML

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-filter/0.5.4/angular-filter.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.1/angular-sanitize.js'></script>
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/2.5.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js'></script>
<script  src="script.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.css'>
 <body ng-app="app">
    <h1>Dynamic accordion: nested lists with html markup</h1>   
  <div ng-controller="AccordionDemoCtrl">
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="item.value">
      <div  ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:item.value">
        <div class="parents"  ng-click="open($index)"><i ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !group.isOpen}"></i> {{ group.title }}        
        </div>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </body>
```

### script.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap','ngSanitize','angular.filter']);
angular.module('app').controller('AccordionDemoCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.oneAtATime = true;

  $scope.open = function (index) {
    $scope.groups[index].isOpen = !$scope.groups[index].isOpen;
    $scope.closeOthers(index);
  }

  $scope.closeOthers = function (index) {
    for(var i = 0; i  < $scope.groups.length; i++) {
       if (i !== index)
        $scope.groups[i].isOpen = false;
    }
  }
$scope.groups[0].isOpen = true;
  $scope.groups = [
    {
      title: 'title 1',


      list: ['<i>item1a</i> blah blah',
        'item2a',
        'item3a']
    },
    {
      title: 'title 2',

      list: ['item1b',
        '<b>item2b </b> blah ',
        'item3b'] 
    },
    {
      title: 'title 3',

    },
    {
      title: 'title 4',

    },
    {
      title: 'title 5',

    }
  ];

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with the filters do not use the index to update the array

try this, here I am passing the item as an filter so we can get to know which node has been asked to be collapsed or expanded. you can use id too to filter the array.

```
<div>
      <input type="text" ng-model="item.value">
      <div  ng-repeat="group in groups | filter:item.value">
        <div class="parents"  ng-click="open(group)"><i ng-class="{'glyphicon-minus': group.isOpen, 'glyphicon-plus': !group.isOpen}"></i> {{ group.title }}        
        </div>
        {{ group.content }}
        <ul class="childs" ng-show="group.isOpen">
          <li ng-repeat="item in group.list">
            <span ng-bind-html="item"></span>
          </li>
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
```

and your controller, we are using that item to filter that out.

```
 $scope.open = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a ===item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = !a.isOpen;
    });
    $scope.closeOthers(item);

  }

  $scope.closeOthers = function (item) {
    $scope.groups.filter(a=> a !==item).forEach(a=>{
      a.isOpen = false;
    });
  }
```

[Demo of plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/IBQZNDgWIKBsqBXQo6SV?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer to open the first div by default I was using $scope.groups[0].isOpen = true,but here in your code how to handle it without initialize from json.

Comment: @carreankush why you want to do that? it is working as expected without doing anything

Comment: yes but to open the first div by default I have used isOpen: true, inside json structure,actually I want to do that without disturbing json structure,that is from outside

Comment: @carreankush check my plunkr link

Comment: here it should come like before,when we click second div it should expand and first one should collapse,again first div is not collapsing here when I want to collapse it

Comment: @carreankush check that link again

Comment: there one small issue when I click first opened div directly to close, its not closing,in second click its closing else every thing is working fine

Comment: @carreankush check again

Comment: still first div is not closing until I click second time on title 1

Comment: @carreankush you can ask another question if you have, I cannot help with your whole project, you need to do something on your own.

Comment: Sure,No problem